# write a recursive function that adds elements in ascending order

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have to write the recursive function insertSort. Given a list of
type x and an element of type x insert the element into the list such
that the list is in ascending order. Duplicates are allowed. The input
list will be properly sorted.

expected output:

```
 insertSort [] 3 -> [3]
    insertSort "btt" ’u’ -> "bttu"
    foldl insertSort [] [] -> []
    foldl insertSort [] [3,1,5,5,3,0,1,8,4] ->
    [0,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,8]
```

I'm new in haskell.I know how to add element but I don't know how to add in ascending order.Please someone help me

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Break down the problem; a, what is the minimum value in a list? b, given a value, what is it's index in a list? c, given an index in a list, how can you create another list with everything except the item at that index?

Comment: The function you're writing isn't the insertion *sort* but rather the *insertion*. You should probably call it `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this may be homework I'll just give hints. Start with the signature

```
isort :: Ord  a =>  [a] -> a -> [a]
```

base case is trivial

```
isort [] x = [x]
```

the recursive case

```
isort (x:xs) y | y <= x =    -- what should happen here since it's at right place
               | otherwise = -- or here, when it's not?
```